# Как сделать, чтобы приходила заявка в телеграмм и на почту?

Tags: php, html, ajax

Как сделать, чтобы приходила заявка в телеграмм и на почту?
Я пытался сделать, чтобы письма приходили на почту и в телеграмм, но ничего не получилось. Стёр код. Вот код, который отсылает письмо на почту.

```
   <?php 
if (!empty($_POST['name']) AND !empty($_POST['email']) AND !empty($_POST['message'])) 
{    
    $theme = "Новое сообщение с сайта";             

    $letter = "Данные сообщения:";
    $letter .="\n\n";
    $letter .="Имя: ".$_POST['name'];
    $letter .="\nEmail: ".$_POST['email'];
    $letter .="\nТелефон: ".$_POST['phone'];
    $letter .="\nСообщение: ".$_POST['message'];

    if (mail("p30000@mail.ru", $theme, $letter, $headers)){
      header("Location: /testform/thankyou.php");
    } else {
      header("Location: /testform");
    }  

} else {
  header("Location: /testform");
}
```

Ребят помогите пожалуйста!!

Comment: У "telegram" есть API, вот документация https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api

Comment: Ну метод отправки письма я бы советовал сменить. Ибо многие такое в спам сразу кидают.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вся документация https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots

1) Создаём бота в telegram (получаем токен бота)

2) Подписываемся на бота и пишем ему сообщение. (это позволит получить id чата)

3) Далее с помощью например cURL шлём запрос методом POST на специальную страницу. Тут описание -> 
https://tlgrm.ru/docs/bots/api#sendmessage